# Allow NULL map values in a custom JsonSerializer

Tags: spring, jackson2, jackson-databind

I have a global object mapper in spring whose property is set like this:

```
getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

This is working correctly and excluding all the null values while serializing.

But I have a custom serializer for a class which has private `Map<String, Object> data = new LinkedHashMap<>()` as a member variable. This map has keys which have null values which I would like to include in my output. Class level or member level @JsonInclude is not working. Tried overriding isEmpty and returning false always, but it didn't work.

NULL map values were automatically included until Jackson 2.5 but this started happening after upgrade to 2.9+. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are looking for is a custom Serializer only for one class right? 
you can find how it is achieved [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization)

And then you can register the serializer to your class

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
class YourClass{
```

This will register the custom serializer to your interested class and this way you can add null values as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've mentioned above that I do have a custom serializer and I'm writing keys with null values as well but they are being ignored while serializing.

Comment: In previous versions we had {@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class, include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.ALWAYS)}, now it's deprecated and not working.

Comment: Oh right sorry I had a problem with understanding the question. sorry any inconvenience occurred.